# BuildRowsetFromXML with a clause

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are currently in the process of trying to bring CMS content in our marketing cloud emails. I have ran in a bit of an issue when I am trying to bring in the pictures.

In a stripped down example of the XML:

```
<TourInfo>
    <Assets>
        <Images>
            <Image Name="route_map" Caption="route_map" Width="297" Height="297" Type="map" Url="https://www.insightvacations.com/-/media/images/maps/iv/2019/europe-2019/romanticeuropeanlonlon_e912b_summer2019_ww.jpg?mw=297&amp;mh=297&amp;bc=white" />
            <Image Name="route_map" Caption="route_map" Width="600" Height="600" Type="map" Url="https://www.insightvacations.com/-/media/images/maps/iv/2019/europe-2019/romanticeuropeanlonlon_e912b_summer2019_ww.jpg" />
            <Image Name="primary_image" Caption="primary_image" Width="125" Height="125" Type="photo" Url="https://www.insightvacations.com/-/media/images/imageupload/tour-images/e912b_125x125_001.jpg" />
            <Image Name="primary_image" Caption="primary_image" Width="531" Height="531" Type="photo" Url="https://www.insightvacations.com/-/media/images/imageupload/tour-images/e912b_531x531_001.jpg" />
            <Image Name="primary_image" Caption="primary_image" Width="1920" Height="660" Type="photo" Url="https://www.insightvacations.com/-/media/images/imageupload/tour-images/e912b_1920x660_001.jpg" />
        </Images>
    </Assets>
</TourInfo>
```

I don't know how to write the BuildRowsetFromXML syntax to get the picture with the following properties `Width="1920" Height="660"`. I need the URL so i can then use the treatascontent with HTTP get.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Giulietta

Answer (score 0):

I realised what I need to do. I wrote the following code:

```
%%[SET @imagesBannerNode=BuildRowsetFromXML(@xmlData,'/TourInfo/Assets/Images/Image',1)
SET @imageBannerURL=Field(Row(@imagesBannerNode,5), 'Url_att')
SET @imageMapURL=Field(Row(@imagesBannerNode,2), 'Url_att')
SET @mapPic=TreatAsContent(HTTPGet(@imageMapURL))
SET @mapBanner=TreatAsContent(HTTPGet(@imageBannerURL))]%%
%%=v(@imageBannerURL)=%%
<br>
%%=v(@imageMapURL)=%%
<br>
Image Map:

    <img src="%%=v(@mapPic)=%%">
<br>
Banner Image 

    <img src="%%=v(@mapBanner)=%%">
```

I am running into a different issue; my HTTPGET returns a string of broken characters and I assume that is because the picture is HTTPs in the XML.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Giulietta

Comment: i managed to solve this by entering in the src the variables that pull the URL so I have skipped the TreatAsContent and HTTPGET altogether